# I am trying to initialize an SDL_Window in a function but it always fails unless I define SDL_Window*win; as a global variable

Tags: c, runtime-error, sdl

I am trying to initialize an SDL_Window in a function but it always fails unless I define SDL_Window*win; as a global variable.  Here is the code:

```
#include<SDL2/SDL.h>
#include<stdio.h>

#define SCREEN_WIDTH 800
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 600
SDL_Surface*Init(SDL_Window*win,char*title,int x,int y,int w,int h,Uint32 flags);

int main(int argc,char**argv){
SDL_Surface *screen=NULL;
SDL_Window*win=NULL;

screen=Init(win,"SDL_Test",
            SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
            SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
            SCREEN_WIDTH,
            SCREEN_HEIGHT,
            SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);

SDL_FillRect(screen,NULL,SDL_MapRGB(screen->format,0xFF,0x00,0x00));
SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(win);
SDL_Delay(2000);


}

SDL_Surface*Init(SDL_Window*win,
                 char*title,
                 int x,
                 int y,
                 int w,
                 int h,
                 Uint32 flags){
SDL_Surface*temp=NULL;

if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING)){
        printf("\nError : %s",SDL_GetError());
        SDL_ClearError();
        return NULL;
}
win=SDL_CreateWindow(title,x,6,w,h,flags);

if(!win){
        printf("\nError: %s",SDL_GetError());
        SDL_ClearError();
        return NULL;
}
temp=SDL_GetWindowSurface(win);
if(!temp){
        printf("\nError: %s",SDL_GetError());
        SDL_ClearError();
        return NULL;
}
return temp;
}
```

If I declare SDL_Window*win as a global variable it shows a red screen(as it should) but if
I define SDL_Window*win in main() and pass it to Init() it show a white screen(error?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not updating `win` in the main function. In `c` you pass variables by value and if you change the value of a pointer ( or win in your case ) the change will not happen outside the function.

The shortest ( but not the best ) solution would be to return window pointer `win` and *then* get the surface with `SDL_GetWindowSurface(win)`